# What'a the difference between "spacious" and "capacious" "source" and resource"?

Tags: differences

I'm doing translation exercise, and it comes to a problem.

I used "***capacious***" to describe a big yard.

(because I learned this word lately.)

Then I check out the answer, it used "***spacious***".

I consult the Oxford Dictionary, and it says:

*Capacious*: **having a lot of space to put things in.**

*Spacious*: **large and with plenty of space for people to move around in.**

well, I still can't figure it out.

Are they just the same ?

Or there is a nuanced difference ？

Next is "***source***" and "***resource***"

I think "*resource*" is a abstract word, like "human resource", "social resource".

While I think "*source*" is a concrete word, like "water source" and "food source", which we can touch or drink or eat.

Is that right?

Comment: For me *spacious* is two-dimensional, whilst *capacious* involves three. I would describe a level car park as *spacious*, but a car boot as *capacious*.

Comment: "capacious" really refers to something's ability to contain other things: its ***capacity*** in other words.  A large bag is capacious because you can carry lots of things in it.  The primary function of a yard **isn't** to contain or carry things, so capacious isn't the best choice.  "spacious" is a more simple proposition - it just means that it's large.

Comment: Well, "capacious" sounds snooty.  And for source/resource you need to provide some context.

Comment: What @MaxWilliams said. Point of view of the observer brings these different connotations: *capacious*: **space within** - point of view of the container; *spacious*: **space without/around** - point of view of something in the container. *We are in a spacious room.* *That thermos is quite capacious!*. These are possible connotations; this does not mean that you cannot use either in place of the other, in many/most contexts.

Comment: @WS2 I think that's part of it, but you could also say that a room was more spacious after you raised the ceiling, so the third dimension can come into play.

Comment: @MaxWilliams Yes. But raising the ceiling wouldn't normally be for the purpose of getting more furniture etc. in. I think *capacious* relates to *capacity*, and the amount of stuff the space will take. A cupboard under the stairs, or a large shopping bag are the types of things which are described as *capacious*, A playing field is *spacious*. *Spacious* seems to celebrate emptiness, and *capacious* the amount of stuff you can cram into it.

Comment: @WS2, I agree, it was really just a comment on how spaciousness can relate to three dimensions, not just two.

Comment: I believe that this question is overly broad in its current scope [because it contains two different questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post). Each pair of comparisons seem mostly unrelated, and should be segregated into separate questions so that the given answers can better address their specific problems, in more direct and orderly fashion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the synonyms section of ODO you'll see that they are considered largely synonymous.

However, spacious ist he [much more common word](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=spacious%2C+capacious&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cspacious%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccapacious%3B%2Cc0), which explains why it would show up as answer in your test.

If we have a look at the [ten most common nouns](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=spacious+*_NOUN%2Ccapacious+*_NOUN&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cspacious%20%2A_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bspacious%20hall_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bspacious%20room_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bspacious%20building_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bspacious%20apartment_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bspacious%20rooms_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bspacious%20plain_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bspacious%20court_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bspacious%20house_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bspacious%20apartments_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bspacious%20edifice_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Ccapacious%20%2A_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bcapacious%20mind_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcapacious%20harbour_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcapacious%20pockets_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcapacious%20bay_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcapacious%20mouth_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcapacious%20pocket_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcapacious%20bosom_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcapacious%20memory_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcapacious%20basin_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcapacious%20stomach_NOUN%3B%2Cc0) that follow the two words we can see a pattern of use. *Spacious* is exclusively used for physical spaces, while *capacious* is also used in a more metaphorical sense being followed mostly by *mind.* There are several words which do not refer to great physical dimensions but, well the capacity to store something or take something in like the *pockets* or the *stomach*.

For the other two words I advise you to have a look at the dictionary as you did with the first two words.

Answer (score 0):

Source is a point of origin.

Resource is typically something or someone of value that can be used to make something.

Someone resourceful is someone capable of taking what's around them to do what needs to be done. Like Macgyver from the TV show is highly resourceful.

A source is often a resource as well.

Comment: This only seems to asnwer half of (too-broad) question. Also, you answer could be improved with sources.